# Next js 14 getting cache cookie when navigating to pages unless their is a hard refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cookies, server-side-rendering

I am creating a small next js 14  booking app without any authentication. I have page called /events which show all list of events and eacch have "Book" button that trigger a function which set details of the events in a cookie and then redirec the user to /booking page.
here is the function.

```
const BookingHandler = async (data:any)=>{
    setLoading({
        'id':(data?.schedule_id+data?.price),
        'isLoading':true  
    })
    
    const bookingSessing = {
        from: parameters?.from,
        where: parameters?.where,
        travel_date: item?.travel_date,
        arrival_time: item?.arrival_time,
        departure_time: item?.departure_time,
        passengers: parameters?.passengers,
        shipper: data?.shipper,
        seatclass: data?.class,
        ship_id: data?.ship_id,
        class_id: data?.class_id,
        schedule_id: data?.schedule_id,
        price: data?.price,
        token: token,
    }

    let encryptBookingSession = encryptdata(JSON.stringify(bookingSessing))

    // If cookie is there then remove it

    let exisitingCookie = getCookie('bookingSession')

    if (exisitingCookie?.valueOf()) {
        deleteCookie('bookingSession')
    }

    setCookie('bookingSession', encryptBookingSession);
    setLoading({
        'id':'',
        'isLoading':false  
    })
    
    router.push(`/booking`)
}
```

and in /booking page I am getting the cookies by its name and rending data which is inside cookie.

```
const Booking = ({ searchParams }: SearchParamPops) => {



const bookingSessiong = cookies().get('bookingSession')

if (!bookingSessiong) {
    return notFound()
}
const decryptBookingSession = JSON.parse(decryptpData(bookingSessiong.value))
const totalPrice = Number(decryptBookingSession?.price) * Number(decryptBookingSession?.passengers)


return ( .....cookies data..... )
```

so this is not getting me update cookie data, it shows the previous cooki data. to get latest cookie data I need to refresh the page manually. How should I tackle this problem, to get the latest cookie when page redirect to /booking page.

Comment: instead of  `router.push(`/booking`)` can you try `redirect("/booking")`.

Comment: `import { redirect } from "next/navigation";`

Comment: this is giving me "Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: NEXT_REDIRECT" when I use redirect.

Comment: do not use it inside `try/catch` block

Comment: no sir, here is the function. 
```js
   const BookingHandler = async (data:any)=>
        const bookingSessing = {
            from: parameters?.from,
            where: parameters?.where,
            travel_date: item?.travel_date, 
            schedule_id: data?.schedule_id,
            price: data?.price,
            token: token,}
        let encryptBookingSession = encryptdata(JSON.stringify(bookingSessing))
        setCookie('bookingSession', encryptBookingSession);
        redirect('/booking')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On `/booking` page:

```
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

const Booking = ({ searchParams }: SearchParamPops) => {

const bookingSessiong = cookies().get('bookingSession')

if (!bookingSessiong) {
    return notFound()
}
const decryptBookingSession = JSON.parse(decryptpData(bookingSessiong.value))
const totalPrice = Number(decryptBookingSession?.price) * Number(decryptBookingSession?.passengers)

return ( .....cookies data..... )
```

Hope this will help you to get the updated cookie value in Next js 14

Comment: no sir not working. I add this line on top of my page 
```
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';
```